# MVC2: Where is HtmlEncode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

In my code I must return Json string, but I can't use HtmlEncode to remove illegal character in MVC2.  How can I encode a string to remove illegal JSON characters?

Answer (score 1):

[System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) can be used without a HttpContext  (using one of the existing Json libraries/classes mentioned in the other answers is probably best, but if you must do what you're asking for, then that's the method you can use)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) open-source library to do your JSON reading/writing

Or you can use the built-in [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

or use the embedded one
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx
you are probably building your own json string. in that case, you'll need to implement different kinds of escaping too, not just removing illegal characters.